# Example of polynomial in two variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Can you please give me an example of a polynomial $F \in K[X,Y]$ such that $V(F)$ is finite?

I found in Fulton the following proposition:

> If F is an irreducible polynomial in $K[X,Y]$ such that $V(F)$ is infinite, then $I(V(F))=(F)$, and $V(F)$ is irreducible.

Is the condition $V(F)$ is infinite necessarily?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $K = \mathbb{R}$ and $F(X,Y) = X^2 + Y^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very easy way: take $K$ to be a finite field and $F$ to be *any* polynomial in $K[X,Y]$.